# Change view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mobile, view

I am new to MVC.

I need to have two views (for same logic) one for normal browser and one for mobile.
How I can I redirect to different view for Mobile?

right now i have two controller but i want to use only one controller (HomeController.cs) for both views.
I know this way, I should have my mobile views under "Home".
Please help me to redirect to Mobile view using only one controller.

i am using below for redirect for now (with two controllers):

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Mobile");

I am using framework 3.5 and MVC 2

Comment: just as an aside I started reading about windows 8 "metro style" apps and it seems they target multiple UI targets intrinsically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having a little trouble picturing your setup. My guess is you have the current setup:

**Controllers**
      - HomeController.cs 
      - MobileController.cs
**Views**
      - Home
          --Index.aspx
      - Mobile
          --Index.aspx

But you want: 
**Controllers**
      - HomeController.cs
**Views**
      - Home
          --Index.aspx
      - Mobile
          --Index.aspx

Is that correct?

### Update:

Aas people mentioned below it's one of those 'that's just how MVC works' sort of deal. 'Home' is a location you can go to, but 'Mobile' is a specific type of page. If you add another area called "About" as new Views subfolder, where would you put your mobile folder? What is mobile now supposed to handle? If mobile is not supposed to replicate the regular site, then it should have its own controller, even if it replicates some code (don't forget you can create classes outside the controllers that can do the brunt of the work that any controller can call). 

On the other hand if you want a mobile version of each of your pages you should be adding them under the views folder for each route. For example:

**Controllers**
      - HomeController.cs
**Views**
      - Home
           - Mobile
             -- Index.aspx
          --Index.aspx

I'm not exactly sure where you are doing the logic to figure out if they are on a mobile platform, but assuming for now it's in the controller somewhere in your HomeController.cs you then have:

```
public ActionResult Index() { 
if([check for mobile])
{
return View("Mobile/Index");
} else {
return View("Index"); 
}
```

Comment: you got it right for my current setup, it is exactly like that. for the new setup i can have it exactly as you suggested or have the Mobile folder under Home folder. I guess it does not make any difference as long as i have separate views for Home and Mobile but use only HomeController.cs. I do the browser detect in Home>>Index ActionResult

Comment: public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {            

            if (MobileHelper.IsMobileDevice(Request.UserAgent))
            {
                
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Mobile");
            }
                         

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }        
    }       above is my current code to redirect to Mobile controller. Now I want to redirect to Home controller but use Mobile view.

Comment: This breaks regular MVC structure. Most view engines will now think Mobile is the name of a controller. This is also a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Yuriy The main reason of my try here is to have only one controller (logic, let's say login) for both views. #boolean got my setup right I just don't know how I should code in HomeController.cs to cover both Mobile and regular view (Home) and how to redirect to Mobile view upon detection(I am using my own helper calss for this). Please be patient with me as i am new to MVC.

Comment: @JohnHey you're having the problem because the controller isn't where this should be done. The code that picks and renders the view happens elsewhere. It is possible to do it in the controller, but it would be very messy, and probably very buggy. The logic where the right view is picked is in the ViewEngine. You can create your own, or use one of the examples in the link I provided. Specifically you'll need to look at the FindView and FindPartialView methods. Those are the methods which take a view name and a context(which you can use to check if you are in mobile), and find the right view.

Comment: Thanks everyone specially Yuriy.
I used the link below as reference and solved the problem with altering the internal view engine.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Add a [Mobile View Engine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I don't want to go for Razor and chtml, I like to use aspx pages.

Comment: @JohnHey that page has the code for using the WebFormViewEngine, note line 3 in the sample.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich - thats for mvc3, the op is on mvc2

Comment: @DanielA.White I'd argue that he should start with MVC 3, but obviously there could be reasons for starting at 2. Regardless, that link has sources for older versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Home Controller**
create To Action like

Public ActionResult Index()
{

}

**And Another Action (Mobile)**

Public ActionResult Mobile()
{

}

**Single Controller Have Many Action(View)**

Controllers
     - HomeController.cs
Views
    - Home
       --Index.chtml
    - Mobile
       --Index.chtml